# Cucumber with Extjs4 choose radio step not working

Tags: cucumber, extjs4, netzke

I'm Working on Ruby on rail 3.1 with Netzke 0.7.4 and Cucumber.

I use Cucumber with Netzke it work great but I have found some problem on choose radio step.

**I use this step.**

```rb
When /^(?:|I )choose "([^"]*)"$/ do |field|
  choose(field)
end
```

**It show this error message.**

```rb
And choose 'Yes' for GST field
  cannot choose field, no radio button with id, name, or label 'Yes' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
(eval):2:in `choose'
```

It's look like `choose(locator)` method can't find any radio button on my page.

That very strange because it have only 2 radio on page.

Question is how can I do with this radio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found answer I search check box instead of combo box and it work.

Is ExtJs 4 transform check box to radio?